# Changing Class Based on Object Properties in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I wish to do the following in my application:
1) access the the property of color and option from each object
2) check the property 
3) give a class based on that property
4) toggle the class onClick

The json object looks like this{

```
{
        "green": false,
        "other": "third",
        "option" : 2
    },
    {     
        "green": false,
        "other": "third",
        "option": 1
    },
    {
        "green": true,
        "other": "first",
        "option": 5
    }
```

And so on...
Each object will be giving back a number for the key ([0],[1] etc).

My React code is as follows:

```
class Inf extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        colorData: data
      }
    }
    renderList(data){
      return(
        <ul>{Object.keys(this.state.colorData).map(thing =><li>{thing}</li>)}</ul>
      )
    }
    render() {
      console.log(this.state.colorData)
      return (
        <div>
        <div>{this.renderList(this.state.colorData)}</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Inf />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

Comment: Just for clarification, you want to choose a class based on the colors which are true in the JSON object? So for example, when green is true, there needs to be a class for it? Or do you just want to set green as the class?

Comment: Ah I see your confusion. So what I would like to do is set the initial state of the object based on the .json and then will be able to toggle the button to change the the property. I will clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you can make use of this library: [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames)

The Usage section of the readme explains it very well, but basically you can then use it to do something like:

`const classes = classNames({ 
   classA: colorData.green, 
   classB: colorData.red 
})`

Basically the className on the left hand side will only be applied if the expression on the right hand side is true. And then you can assign the `classes` to the react className prop

Comment: classnames solves the problem, it picks only those keys from object whose values are Boolean(true), and then concatenates them with one space into a string.

Answer (score 0):

In your `renderList` function, you can style the `li` returned by your map with `className={desiredClass}`.

There are two variables I'm not sure about in your question:

1. what key you're storing color under in the object
2. how you determine which class to add based on this color

I assume you use `.color` and then have a function `classBasedOnColor` to apply a class name based on this color. You could also use a dictionary with color keys and class name values.

It would look like this:

```
<ul>{Object.keys(this.state.colorData).map(thing=>{
  const color = this.state.colorData[thing].color;
  const desiredClass=classBasedOnColor(color);
  return <li className={desiredClass}>{thing}</li>
})}</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Right now the code's key is returning a series of numbers based on the number of the object in the .json as a result I am having a difficult time accessing the information from each property. So what I want to do is if the class returns "true" then the css class for green but the class can be toggled.

Comment: Hi sacora no problem — I just want to make sure I understand what you're going for. If I understand correctly, the colors could look like this: 
`colors: { green: true, blue: false, red: true }` and you would want to add classes for `.color-green` and `.color-red`?

If so, you can generate your class list like this:
`Object.keys(colors).filter(key=>colors[key]).map(e=>'color-'+e).join(" ")`
That gives you `color-green color-red` for the example object.

Comment: Yes, that would be true for the color properties. In the full .json there is also some properties which are not booleans however which I will also be accessing through a similar method for example type: first  type: third or something like that. I will add a non-boolean example to the question so you can see what I mean.

Comment: The point is to ignore these non-boolean (non-color key) types, correct? If I understand, we are only looking at color properties and ignoring the others. It'd help if you could post a bit more of the JSON, or a bit more code to see what you're going for here.

Comment: Yes, that way it will be more applicable to other parts of the json. The code is the full code but I can expand out the .json. I also realized that i did say specifically color before (as to limit the scope for the example) but to be more accurate I would want to access other information from the object as well.

Comment: In that case, I'd either maintain a list of colors that you can use to return a filtered list of color keys from your object, generating class names based on this filtered list, or keep all the color keys within a single key in your JSON, say an array of objects, like `[{'red':true, 'blue':false}]`, that you can iterate through and generate `className`s.